# Authentication with private BitBucket repository to clone with JGit

Tags: git, bitbucket, jgit

I want to clone a remote private Atlassian BitBucket repository to my computer.

Could you please describe the process how it can be done.

I'm especially interested in the authentication process. Do I need to use (for Atlassian BitBucket) `UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider` as a `CredentialsProvider` and that's it or some other steps should be performed in order to do this?

**UPDATED**

I tried the following solution:

```java
    SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void configure(Host host, Session session) {
            session.setPassword( "password" );
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        }
    };
    CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
    cloneCommand.setURI("ssh://user@bitbucket.org/reponame.git");
    //cloneCommand.setURI("git@bitbucket.org:user/reponame.git");
    cloneCommand.setDirectory(new File("reponame"));
    cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {
        @Override
        public void configure(Transport transport) {
            SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
            sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
        }
    }); 
    cloneCommand.call();
```

but it fails with the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:user/reponame.git: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200)
    at com.bitbucket.BitBucketTest.cloneViaSsh(BitBucketTest.java:63)
    at com.bitbucket.BitBucketTest.main(BitBucketTest.java:39)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:user/reponame.git: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:237)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:126)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html), Bitbucket allows authenticating through SSH. In this case you don't need a `CredentialsProvider`.

However, you may need to provide an `SshSessionFactory`.

```java
SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
  @Override
  protected void configure( Host host, Session session ) {
    // ...
  }
};
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
cloneCommand.setURI( "ssh://user@example.com/repo.git" );
cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback( new TransportConfigCallback() {
  @Override
  public void configure( Transport transport ) {
    SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
    sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( sshSessionFactory );
  }
} );
```

Note, that in `TransportConfigCallback::configure`, the transport argument is blindly cast to `SshTransport`, meaning that this `TransportConfigCallback` will only work with SSH URLs.

If your Bitbucket server requires password-secured SSH connections, you can provide the password in the `SshSessionFactory`'s `configure` method, e.g.

```java
SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
  @Override
  protected void configure( Host host, Session session ) {
    session.setPassword( "password" );
  }
} );
```

The private keys are loaded from `<user-home>/.ssh`. If your private key file is named differently or located elsewhere, I recommend to override `createDefaultJSch()`. After calling the base method, custom private keys can be added like so:

```java
@Override
protected JSch createDefaultJSch( FS fs ) throws JSchException {
  JSch defaultJSch = super.createDefaultJSch( fs );
  defaultJSch.addIdentity( "/path/to/private_key" );
  return defaultJSch;
}
```

For further details, you may want to read [JGit Authentication Explained](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/), an article that I wrote some years ago.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please check my updated question because your solution fails with the exception. What can be a reason of this and how to fix it?

Comment: I use the password that I use for https access. In case of https it is working.. in case of ssh - fails.

Comment: Did you try without setting a password? Where is your local ssh directory located? Does the ssh URL match the Bitbucket specification?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, I'm testing this functionality on my Windows 10 machine so I'm not sure about ssh directory here. Test URL I copied from BitBucket directly. By the way  - the solution based on https is working fine. I'm only unable to clone the repo via Java and this ssh approach...

Comment: Please see my edited answer for where SSH keys are searched.

Comment: Thanks, I have provided the path to my private key but it fails right now with the following exception: `Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail`

Comment: Finally, I got it working. I added my `passphrase` to `defaultJSch.addIdentity` method. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after reading Rudger Herrmann's solutions I still had User Auth fails. I found adding the line: `defaultJSch.removeAllIdentity();` into the overridden `createDefaultJSch` before you add your own identity fixed the issue:

```
@Override
protected JSch createDefaultJSch(FS fs) throws JSchException {
    JSch defaultJSch = super.createDefaultJSch(fs);
    defaultJSch.removeAllIdentity();
    defaultJSch.addIdentity("path/to/key", "password");
    return defaultJSch;
}
```

I guess this prevents the `defaultJSch` from using some weird default configuration and it forces it to use your added identity? Additionally, adding the password in `defaultJSch::addIdentity` makes adding the password in `configure` optional.